# How to conditionally add [matMenuTriggerFor] in mat-menu

Tags: angular, angular-material

Few `#menu` items has no sub child. But shows the arrow which indicates there is a submenu. Which is wrong.
How to add `[matMenuTriggerFor]="subMenu"` only when there are items in subMenu.

```html
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of menuItem.items; let i=index"> 
        <button class="mat-menu-item" mat-menu-item
            [routerLink]="item.routerLink" routerLinkActive="active" [matMenuTriggerFor]="subMenu"> {{item.name}}
        </button>
        <mat-menu #subMenu="matMenu"> <button class="mat-sub-menu-item"
                *ngFor="let subitem of menuItem.items[i].subitems" mat-menu-item> {{ subitem.name }} </button>
        </mat-menu>
    </ng-container>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: just a guess: [matMenuTriggerFor]="menuItems.length > 0 ? subMenu : null"

Comment: submenu items are part of menuItem.items[i].subitems array.

Comment: [{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Clients",
      "icon": "perm_identity",
      "items": [{
          "name": "Manage Clients",
          "routerLink": "/Object/Contact",
          "subitems":[{
            "name":"Sub Client 1"
          }]
        },
        {
          "name": "Manage Accounts",
          "routerLink": "/Object/Account"
        }
      ]
    }]

Comment: it was just an example of course. `menuItems` could be any var

Comment: yeah sure..But  [matMenuTriggerFor]="item.subitems.length > 0 ? subMenu : null" doesnot work either.

Answer (score 4):

The functionality to implement conditional [matMenuTriggerFor] is implemented and will be presented in the next versions of angular:
https://github.com/angular/components/commit/856c01639fbf968cb33885807ffaf6d3f3bf5423

Until then I am using the next workaround:

HTML

```
<button [matMenuTriggerFor]="condition ? menu : placeholder"/><button>
<mat-menu #placeholder="matMenu" class="placeholder"></mat-menu>
```

CSS

```
.placeholder {
  display: none;
}
```

In your case + conditional styles to hide arrow.

Comment: Note for anyone else finding this that tries to shortcut Carl's answer like I did! You cannot apply the class conditionally - it won't get promoted to the overlay (which Menu uses). Similarly you can't do `[style.display]="condition ? 'none' : null"` and finally the `.placeholder` class must be declared globally (you can actually use `::ng-deep { .placeholder { display: none; } }` in a component to achieve this.

Comment: This solution will keep the menu open in the background, which will prevent the user from clicking other elements.

Answer (score 1):

My Solution is - to do other ng-template for cases that there is sub menu.

To pass

```
  [matMenuTriggerFor]="somecondition? subMenu: null"
```

Will generate error, in some version, anyway.

for Example:

```
 <a *ngIf="conditionForNoSubMenu; else submenuItem">My buttons...</a>

    <ng-template #submenuItem>
      <a
        [matMenuTriggerFor]=" subMenu"
      >My Buttons.... 
        <mat-menu #subMenu="matMenu">
          my sub buttons.... 
        </mat-menu>
      </a>

    </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

For angular version 14 and above, you can pass in null `[matMenuTriggerFor]="condition ? menu : null`

For versions below it, I used `*ngIf` twice, one with `[matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"` and one without it.

```
<span *ngIf="condition" class="clickable" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">click for menu</span>
<span *ngIf="!condition">click for nothing</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue by adding *ngIf="menuItem.items[i].subitems" to the button

```html
<button class="mat-menu-item" [class.more-menu-item]="menuItem.name=='More'"  mat-menu-item  [routerLink]="item.routerLink"
        routerLinkActive="active" [matMenuTriggerFor]="subMenu"><span class="pm-menu-item">{{item.name}}</span><i class="material-icons pm-menu-icon-right" *ngIf="menuItem.items[i].subitems">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
 </button>
```

Comment: This solved your problem, which is a win for you, but doesn't answer the original question, so it's not likely to be helpful to others finding this. Would be nice to see an answer or good workaround for cases where the target element needs to remain visible but only conditionally respond with a menu.