# Angular MatMenu with optional sub menu

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a MatMenu with a optional sub-menu. The same button, if `haveSubmenu` open another matMenu otherwise on click make other operation... eg.:

```html
<mat-menu #showMenu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="haveSubmenu ? haveSubmenu : null" (click)="onClick()">
        Sub Menu
    </button>
</mat-menu>
```

`matMenuTriggerFor` not accepts `null` as value... How to make `matMenuTriggerFor` optional?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to conditionally add \[matMenuTriggerFor\] in mat-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364802/how-to-conditionally-add-matmenutriggerfor-in-mat-menu)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply use ngIf with a button with subMenu and a button without like this?

```
<mat-menu #showMenu="matMenu">
   <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="haveSubmenu" [matMenuTriggerFor]="subMenu"> 
        Sub Menu        
  </button>    
  <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="!haveSubmenu">
        No Sub Menu
  </button> 
</mat-menu>
```

Edit:
In case you have a list you can use it like this:

component.ts:

```
  public buttons: {label: string, hasSubmenu: boolean} = [...]
```

html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let button of buttons">
    <mat-menu #showMenu="matMenu">
       <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="button.hasSubmenu" [matMenuTriggerFor]="subMenu"> 
            {{button.label}}       
      </button>    
      <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="!button.hasSubmenu">
            {{button.label}}  
      </button> 
    </mat-menu>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I have multiple button and I don't want replicate button everyware

Comment: @ar099968 i updated my answer for lists of buttons